# Moving Android Studio Projects and Configurations from Windows 7 to OS X

Tags: android, windows, macos, android-studio

Currently I am running Android Studio on a XPS 17 that is running Windows 7.  I want to get a MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite.

Will I be able to transfer my Android Studio Projects from Windows to OS X without the risk of losing my projects and is there a proper way to go about doing it? Would it also be possible to keep my current configurations by transferring the configurations file from my Windows version of Android Studio or will it need to be reconfigured manually?

Is there anything else that I need to be aware of before making the switch?  Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you will be able to switch seamlessly, I frequently use Linux/Windows/OS X Yosemite for the same project.

Just open Android Studio and click on "Open an existing Android Studio project" and point to your project.

For the setttings you may go to File>Export Settings (on your Android Studio for Windows) then on Android Studio for Mac File>Import Settings.

Comment: Any problems with this method try the Import project Eclipse, Gradle etc.

Comment: I have my project on a windows PC on the network and my mac sees that folder but was not able to compile because could not write to the folder.